# Django / Getting a specific queryset in ListView

Tags: python, django

I want to get specific queryset inside my ListView class. The queryset that I want to get is:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=username)
```

However, since ListView is class-based view, I can't define what I want.
I tried like this:

```
**views.py**


class PostListView(ListView):

    model = Post
    template_name = 'itu_forum/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']    # for normal view [date_posted]
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(PostListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ctx['title'] = 'Ana Sayfa'
        return ctx


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(author.username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

This is the url I want to use. I want to get to specific user's profile:

```
**urls.py**

path('profile/<str:username>/', views.user_profile, name='user-profile')
```

href in My Template:

```
href="{%url 'user-profile' queryset.username %}
```

I completely messed up. Need help.

Comment: And what exactly is going wrong with the code you're showing? "it's not working" doesn't describe a problem. Tell us the behaviour you see that is not what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

you can do

```
 def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(PostListView, self).get_queryset()
    return queryset.filter(author.username=self.request.user.username)
```